# Why hibernate id's are not getting increased when deployed in two servers in jboss 7.1.1 community version

Tags: hibernate, load-balancing, primary-key, jboss7.x, hibernate3

I have developed a web application with the configuration hibernate 3 and jboss 6.4.0 EAP, now I have migrated my application to jboss 7.1.1 community version. When I first deployed the application my primary key id's are not getting increased, then I went to jboss 7.1.1 migration guide and got to know that jboss 7.1.1 will generate it's own id's, so for getting my old id's I have used

```
`<property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings" value="false"/>`
```

line in my standalone.xml file then my problem has been solved and id's are generating in the old way. Now I have configured another server and deployed same application in the second server now I am getting the same exception that is id's are not getting increased. I don't know what is the exact problem, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: are both deployed applications pointing to same DB and running concurrently ? - this might be cause.

Comment: @PriyankaW, I am deploying single application in two servers and requests are being shared by load balancer.

Comment: hello, if you have solved issue please let us know. i understood you have one working application on jboss 7.1.1. what is version of another server ? does that another server also have `<property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings" value="false"/>` in standalone.xml like your 1st jboss server ?